# Java Convention to Return List of Own Instances?

Tags: java, coding-style, convention

I have a question about Java Coding Style.

I coded:

```
public class Pattern {
    public Pattern(...) { ... }

    public static List<Pattern> generatePatterns( ... ) { ... }
}
```

Since class instances do not contain static functions I think there is no problem, however, it feels awkward to statically generate a list of own instances from inside...?

What do you think?

Comment: I think it's fine.

Comment: You could move it to a utility class if you wanted to, but it's entirely personal preference.

Comment: A factory method like that as a static member of the class itself is a widespread and standard idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, **static** can be seen as abnormality in good OO design. Meaning: you are careful about using it, as it leads to direct coupling of your classes, kills polymorphism and leads to hard-to-test code.

But sometimes, static methods are ok; for example to have specific "generator" methods. Think of Optionals.of() or the various methods in Collections.

From that perspective, your example seems to be fine. But we can't tell you whether your implementation of this method is as such that making it static is beneficial in the long term.

Comment: Thanks. I really like the swift keyboard app, but it still requires to pay a bit of attention :-)

Comment: We can tell you that your implementation of this method as `static` is, in fact, beneficial in the long, medium, and short term.

Comment: You can? I have seen to many static methods that required our stack to be *running* in order to function. Such code immediately breaks reasonable unit testing. The "smart" people responsible for that code crime then look at you : "just use PowerMock and mock the static call". That is way I prefer to remind people about the potential negative side effects of static. So yes, a small factory method is probably fine; but few things are so simple that even a dedicated mind can't blow them up :-)